# How to use vector as argumant in odeint scipt

Tags: vector, scipy, odeint

this is My Code:

```
Ue=2.16
#Ta=np.random.randint(20,30,24)
Ta=34
A=3
C=1000*750*0.15
h=6
Gc=h*A

def C001(T,t,Ue,A,C,Gc,Ta):
    T1,T2=T
    dTdt=[
          (Ue*A*(T2-T1)+Gc*(Ta-T1))/C,
          (Ue*A*(T1-T2)+Gc*(Ta-T2))/C]
           
    return dTdt

Ts=[25,25] #initial conditions
t=np.linspace(0,24,24)*3600  #integration interval
result=odeint(C001,Ts,t,args=(Ue,A,C,Gc,Ta))

fig , ax=plt.subplots()
ax.plot(t/3600,result[:,1],color='tab:red')
ax.grid()
ax.set_xlabel('Time (Hours)'
```

The problem is :
whene i try to replace Ta with np array so it is integrated with time t i get an error of
"The array return by func must be one-dimensional, but got ndim=2." even though the vector t and Ta has the same shape (24,)

Comment: `T` is a 1d array `[T1,T2]`, and `dTdt` is (should) be as well.  Making `Ta` an array changes that, which is unacceptable.

Comment: so i must change T to have the same dim as Ta (24,) , can you tell how Do i do that ?